# "Calendar is not defined" when attempting to run Google's "Vacation Calendar" sample code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to run [Google's sample code for a vacation calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar). When I attempt to do so, I get the following error:

> Calendar is not defined

I looked at the code and it stems from this line of code:

```
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
```

How do I get this line of code to not error out?

Comment: Maybe enable the calendar API

Comment: Basically turn on the [advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

Since it's using `Calendar` instead of `CalendarApp` in the script, it's using the advanced service, so you must [explicitly enable the Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). Don't forget to name it `Calendar` so you don't need to tweak the code.

---

Long answer...

Each service has two methods of invocation: `FooApp` and `Foo`. For example, `CalendarApp` and `Calendar`.

Here are the differences:

### CalendarApp

- The default mechanism for interacting with a service.
- Automatically enabled by default.
- [Simple API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date)) with arguments / code completion:

  ```
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, twoHoursFromNow);
  ```
- Access documentation via Support > Documentation > Google Apps Scripts > Reference > [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar)

### Calendar (also called `Calendar API`)

- The "advanced" method of interacting with a service.
- Must be enabled via an [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) (where you will also give it the name `Calendar`).
- [Advanced API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) with dictionary parameters:

  ```
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
  ```
- Access documentation via Support > Documentation > Google Apps Scripts > Reference > Calendar > Calendar API > Google Calendar API > Calendar API > [Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference)

---

Note that in the above example, I used Calendar everywhere, but the same applies to all the other services (e.g. Gmail and GmailApp).

If you go to the reference for Calendar > [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar), you can see this documented by Google:

> The advanced Calendar service allows you to use the public Google Calendar API in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's built-in Calendar service, this API allows scripts to access and modify the user's Google Calendar, including additional calendars that the user is subscribed to. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this advanced service provides a few extra features, including setting the background color for individual events.